# Почему так себя ведет window.location.assign

Tags: javascript

пытаюсь загрузить документ по указанному url после выполнения скрипта следующим образом скрипт отрабатывает по этому url

`mySite.loc/admin/menu/menuget/create`

вот html

```
<a href='#' id='#secures' data-formurl='/admin/menu/menuget'>Click</a>
```

вот javascript

```
$('#secures').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault;
     var path = $('#secures').data('formurl');
     window.location.assign(window.location.hostname+path);
}
```

но вот почему то получаю следующий адрес `mySite.loc/admin/menu/menuget/mySite.loc/admin/menu/menuget` почему не подскажете ?

Comment: `...ntDefault();`

Comment: @Igor вы думаете это живой код ? Накидал по памяти как собыете отменить. У меня там вообще отправка формы и return false  я разве жаловался на e.preventDefault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.hostname` возвращает вам домен без протокола, и `.assign()` формирует относительный путь, подставляя в начале ваш текущий урл.

И еще, вместо `§('#sequre').data('formurl')` лучше используйте `§(e.currentTarget).data('formurl')`, вдруг у вас там дубль с таким же id. Ну и `preventDefault` это функция.

Comment: То есть надо добавить протокол ? Насчет id  нет не будет дубляжа.